# Trouble on creating a Component wrapper using styled-component and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Creating a components library, I wanted to include the layout components directly in the library. For that I just created the classics component (`Container`, `Row` and `Col`) which is actually just a copy of the ones from the library [react-grid-system](https://github.com/sealninja/react-grid-system).

So for example, my component `Col` look like that:

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Col as ReactGridSystemCol, ColProps } from 'react-grid-system';

// C O M P O N E N T
const Col: React.FunctionComponent<ColProps> = (props) => {
  const { children } = props

  return (
    <StyledCol {...props}>
      {children}
    </StyledCol>
  )
}

// S T Y L E S
const StyledCol = styled<ColProps>(ReactGridSystemCol)` // <- Type 'ColProps' does not satisfy the constraint '"symbol" | "object" ...
  /* ... */
`

StyledCol.displayName = 'StyledCol'

export default Col
```

Logically, I say that my `StyledCol` component inherits from the `ReactGridSystemCol` component, so I will be able to add styles to this one and it will be rendered in my jsx.

Then I have to manage the props that my `Col` component can receive. They are exactly the same as those of `ReactGridSystemCol`, so I use the type of the library, `ColProps`.

I then indicate that `StyledCol` can receive this props using `styled<ColProps>(ReactGridSystemCol)`.

The problem is that visibly there is a type error because typescript returns this error:

```
Type 'ColProps' does not satisfy the constraint '"symbol" | "object" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "body" | "br" | "button" | "canvas" | ... 157 more ... | FunctionComponent<...>'.
  Type 'ColProps' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any>'.
    Type 'ClassAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & { width?: string | number | undefined; ... 5 more ...; component?: (() => string) | undefined; } & Partial<...>' provides no match for the signature '(props: any, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
```

I don't quite understand my mistake here so if you have any ideas I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
const StyledCol = styled(ReactGridSystemCol)<ColProps>``
```

Comment: Yeah it fix the first error but I get then a another one directly on the `<StyledCol>` component: `Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.` Have you  an idea how it's possible because I use the same type `ColProps` everywhere :/